# R, list: how to get nested value using a name?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Well, I’m not too familiar with lists yet. I’d like to separate a value from inside the list using a name on the same level.

Example:

```
a <- data.frame("value" = 10, "title" = "A")
b <- data.frame("value" = 20, "title" = "B")
c <- data.frame("value" = 30, "title" = "C")
d <- data.frame("value" = 40, "title" = "D")
e <- list("a" = a, "b"= b)
f <- list("c" = c, "d" = d)

x <- list("e" = e, "f" = f)
rm(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

This is how the list x looks like:

```
$e
$e$a
  value title
    10     A

$e$b
  value title
    20     B


$f
$f$c
  value title
    30     C

$f$d
  value title
    40     D
```

I can get a value with `x$f$c$value` for example. But is there a way how to get the same value 30, if I know only title D on the same list level? To get 30 using D.

Answer (score 0):

We could try

```
rbindlist(x$f)[title!="D",]
   value title
1:    30     C

#If just want value
rbindlist(x$f)[title!="D",]$value
#[1] 30
```

Comment: Thank you. This method needs to enter the preceding branch name and it is not always known. The list could be more nested than in my example.

Comment: Didn't you say `I know only title D on the same list level` ?

Comment: Yes, only title D and that D is on the same level as value. But I don't know absolute address of this level (names above D).